# Preg_match - retrieving href

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have got stuck with a question I have just been helped on - its a new problem but only just slightly.

I have this preg_match to get the contents of href. Please don't tell me not to use regex - I am aware of using other parsers/classes etc but this is an old script that just needs to be fixed for now. :) No time for re-writes!

```
preg_match("~<a target=\'_blank\' rel=\'nofollow\' href=\"(.*?)\">~i", $epilink, $epiurl);
```

It returns:

```
http://www.example.com/frame2.php?view=&epi=54673-r
```

However, it should return:

```
http://www.example.com/frame2.php?view=168204&epi=54673
```

This is an example of html it would work with:

```
<a target='_blank' rel='nofollow' href="http://www.example.com/frame2.php?view=545903&epi=54683">
```

Why is the URL I have returned malformed?

Thanks all for any help.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the string you're passing it.

Comment: The variable `$epilink` - contains some html with at least one url which i have pasted as an example. Would my regex work with that?

Comment: It would. However, if there are any other strings earlier in the text that match, it will grab those instead.

Comment: @Anon how would I get it match just one of those urls then?

Comment: You should use an HTML parser instead. Walk the DOM to find all your `<a>` tags, and grab the `href` property of any ones with `_blank` as the target and `nofollow` set. It'll be a far easier fix than trying to hack up this regex.

Comment: I understand that preg_match should match once and then return, so i can't see why other html elements or other valid matches that exist can cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string="<a target='_blank' rel='nofollow' href=\"http://www.example.com/frame2.php?view=545903&epi=54683\">";
$s = explode('">',$string);
foreach($s as $k){
   if (strpos($k,"href")!==FALSE){
        echo preg_replace('/.*href="|/ms',"",$k);
        break;
   }
}
```

output

```
$ php test.php
http://www.example.com/frame2.php?view=545903&epi=54683
```

Comment: The string will contain more html. As I have said to Anon how would I just get one match? Btw, thanks for replying to my previous question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`$epilink = "<a target='_blank' rel='nofollow' href=\"http://www.example.com/frame2.php?view=545903&epi=54683\">";
preg_match("/<a target='_blank' rel='nofollow' href=\"(.*?)\">/i", $epilink, $epiurl);`

print_r($epiurl);

you can also use **preg_match_all**